# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser, парсинг ссылки

Tags: simple-html-dom, php, синтаксический-анализ

Доброго Нового года!
Есть задача спарсить только значение тега `<a>` (в данном примере "МВО"), отдельно в него  входит `<div>` с классом.

```
<a href="#" rel="3" title="масловодоотталкивающая отделка" class="seq">МВО
<div class="tooltip_cont">
<h5>МВО - масловодоотталкивающая отделка</h5>
<p>Благодаря масловодоотталкивающей отделке ткань препятствует проникновению воды и жировых, масляных жидкостей, сохраняя при этом воздухо- (паро- ) проницаемость ( ткань пропускает пары пота). Тестирование проводится нанесением тестирующих жидкостей по  методике ф. "3М".</p>
</div>
</a>
```

Мой код:

```
 foreach ($html->find('a.seq') as $a) {
                echo $a;
            }
```

Выводит целиком все содержимое элемента `<a>` вместе с `<div>`, а нужно только значение ссылки ("МВО").
chilren, parent не помогают.

Помогите решить задачу.

Comment: Вам надо, разумеется,

    echo $a->href;

Ссылка равна `#`, очевидно. Вы уверены, что вам надо именно это? Небось настоящая ссылка выставляется джаваскриптом на `onclick`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Намного проще воспользоваться встроенным классом.
**Идея:** ищем ссылку с нужным классом -> удаляем все вложенные элементы. После этого останется только внутренний текст, который не принадлежит внутренним элементам.
**Демонстрация:**  http://ideone.com/nhFd5p
**Код:**

```
<?php

$html = '<a href="#" rel="3" title="масловодоотталкивающая отделка" class="seq">МВО
<div class="tooltip_cont">
<h5>МВО - масловодоотталкивающая отделка</h5>
<p>Благодаря масловодоотталкивающей отделке ткань препятствует проникновению воды и жировых, масляных жидкостей, сохраняя при этом воздухо- (паро- ) проницаемость ( ткань пропускает пары пота). Тестирование проводится нанесением тестирующих жидкостей по  методике ф. "3М".</p>
</div>
</a>';

$output = array();

$doc = new DomDocument();

$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $html);

/* Корректно обрабатываем UTF-8 */
// dirty fix
foreach ($doc->childNodes as $item)
    if ($item->nodeType == XML_PI_NODE)
        $doc->removeChild($item); // remove hack
$doc->encoding = 'UTF-8'; // insert proper

$urls = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($urls as $url) {

    if ($url->getAttribute('class') === 'seq') {

        $childs = $url->getElementsByTagName('*');

        foreach ($childs as $child) {
            $url->removeChild($child);
        }

        $output[] = trim($url->nodeValue);
    }

}

print_r($output);
```

Comment: Все работает, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Этот вариант покороче, только с применением Simple HTML DOM

```
<?php
require_once 'simp/simple_html_dom.php';
$data = str_get_html(file_get_contents("m.html"));
$data->find('a',0)->children('0')->outertext='';
echo $data->find('a',0)->innertext;
?>
```

Comment: Добавьте описание Вашего ответа